# Android studio build fail transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my build error. Don't know what to do. I don't know what this could relate to at all. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. I've been stuck on this for an hour.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
```

This is what my debug says

```
17:31:52.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:31:52.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:31:52.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:31:52.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
17:31:52.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':myapp:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:31:52.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
17:31:52.903 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
17:31:52.903 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Comment: Curt, click in "Run with --debug" and get the error message.

Comment: Added it in my question.

Comment: have you multiDex support enabled ?

Comment: Yes, I have multiDex set to true  multiDexEnabled = true

Comment: android.enableAapt2=true fixed it for me.  I had android.enableAapt2=false as when i build production builds the long file names were stopping it from working.  See if setting this in your gradle.build file fixes your issue.